# Deleting a specific comment off an array (JS)

Tags: javascript, dom, rendering

I've got a module that renders a "posts" array (coming from another .js file) to the DOM. 
one of it functions should be deleting a specific comment when clicking an icon asides it. 
I know I need to give them a class that will identify and make the icon-comment connection but can't seem to get it done. 
Can someone help?

Example of the posts array :

```
let _posts = [
    {
        text: "First post!",
        id: "p1",
        comments: [
            { id: "c1", text: "First comment on first post!" },
            { id: "c2", text: "Second comment on first post!!" },
            { id: "c3", text: "Third comment on first post!!!" }
        ]
    },
    {
        text: "Aw man, I wanted to be first",
        id: "p2",
        comments: [
            { id: "c4", text: "Don't wory second poster, you'll be first one day." },
            { id: "c5", text: "Yeah, believe in yourself!" },
            { id: "c6", text: "Haha second place what a joke." }
        ]
    }
]
```

The render module itself :

```
const Renderer = function() {
  const renderPosts = function(posts) {
    $("#posts").empty()

    for (index in posts) {
      let newDiv = $(`<div class=post><div class=post-text id=${posts[index].id}>${posts[index].text}
                </div>`)
      $("body").append(newDiv)
      for (let index2 in posts[index].comments) {

        let newDiv2 = $(`<div class=comments id=${posts[index].comments[index2].id}><i id="delete-comment" class="fas fa-minus-circle"></i> ${posts[index].comments[index2].text}</div></div>`)
        $(`#${posts[index].id}`).append(newDiv2)
        let $deleteComment = $(".comments")

        $("body").on("click", "#delete-comment", function() {
          $deleteComment.remove();
        });

      }
    }

  }
  return {
    renderPosts
  }
}
```

Much thanks and sorry if at first moment the code formatting didn't go well, I couldn't find a way to move all chars the way I wanted. Will edit with your help if needed

Answer (score 1):

IDs should be unique, you shouldn't have `id="delete-comment"` in every post. That should be a class.

I've added a `data-id` attribute to the delete button, that contains the ID of the comment.

When you're using event delegation, you only need to do it once, not inside the loop that creates the element.

```js
const Renderer = function() {
  const renderPosts = function(posts) {
    $("#posts").empty()
    for (index in posts) {
      let newDiv = $(`<div class=post><div class=post-text id=${posts[index].id}>${posts[index].text}
                </div>`)
      $("body").append(newDiv)
      for (let index2 in posts[index].comments) {
        let newDiv2 = $(`<div class=comments id="${posts[index].comments[index2].id}"><i class="fas fa-minus-circle delete-comment" data-id="${posts[index].comments[index2].id}"></i> ${posts[index].comments[index2].text}</div></div>`);
        $(`#${posts[index].id}`).append(newDiv2);
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    renderPosts
  }
}

$("body").on("click", ".delete-comment", function() {
  $(`#${$(this).data('id')}`).remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank u ! working (after modifying the event to be on "body" instead of "#posts"). It was a good lesson

Comment: I saw `$("#posts").empty()`, so I thought that was what you were appending the posts to.